# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67: Como obtener token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tokens

Intento guardar una nota a través del método **Store** con una pedicion `POST` a la ruta `/categorias`, si me logueo en el sistema funciona correctamente, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo a través de PostMan, entiendo que no se va a poder nunca por que debo estar autentificado antes para poder hacerlo.

La intención de todo esto es que quiero hacerlo desde una App en android enviando la petición por la URI y según me doy cuenta necesito enviar el token.. pero no tengo ni idea de como obtener el token del usuario ni como enviarlo.

**Ruta**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::resource('/categorias','NoteController');
});
```

**Controlador**

```
public function store()
{
    $note = new Note();
    try {
        $note->text = 'Primera Nota';
        $note->user_id = Auth::user()->id();
        Log::info('Nota Creata');
    } Catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::critical('Erro al registrar la nota');
    }
}
```

PDT: intento hacer login con postman a la ruta `/login` enviando los parámetros `email,password` tal como los tiene el formulario login de laravel  y me doy cuenta que tiene un atributo oculto `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">` que no se como enviarlo en la petición :(

Comment: Esto está en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf), léala por favor. Debes agregar el token a la peticion post, si agregas esta linea `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` al head de tu sitio quizá te sirva `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` para obtener el token. Mira este [gist](https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0). Si haces una api para Android, te recomiendo que uses otro tipo de seguridad.

Comment: gracias por la información, voy a intentar la autenticación con  AngularJS un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se loguea por primera vez deberías devolver el Token a la aplicación y utilizarlo para las demás operaciones.

Puedes utilizar JWT-Auth para obtener los tokens. Aquí hay más información sobre esto: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por el comentario, seguí el tutoríal que enviaste, pero no funciona los comandos que provee no funcionan no encuentra la clase `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,` indagando en google encontré que en ves de esa clase es la siguiente `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class, ` después quise registrar el provider tampoco funciono ni genera la clave :(

Comment: Cuál comando no te funciona?